# Flutter app stuck on Installing and Launching step for physical iPhone

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter, visual-studio-code

Annoying problem here for my Flutter app: iOS13.3, Xcode11.3 on a physical iPhoneX. The iOS-Simulators all work. The problem is only happening on a physical device. The Flutter App freezes at startup (i.e. at Installing and Launching... step) ! Any ideas ??
My flutter doctor -v does not bring any problems. Also tried flutter clean and flutter upgrade. But nothing seems to fix the problem...

If I run the App from Xcode (Runner.xcworkspace) then everything works as well. Only from VSCode and Flutter, I can no longer launch my physical iPhoneX.

Also, when uploaded to TestFlight, the App freezes at App Start ! (grey screen freeze). Therefore Apple App Store rejects all Flutter Apps for now ! Very annoying.

I am not sure if the Installing and Launching... freeze is related to the TestFlight and App Store Problem !! Might as well be...

Comment: Try `flutter run -v` to see more detail log maybe is some thing crashed at app start up.

Comment: Thank you, I have a look at this.

Comment: This is a [workaround solution](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/47204#issuecomment-570832706) - after that it works!!

Answer (score 5):

This fixed the issue for me:

1. Run the app from Xcode.
2. Disable WiFi on iPhone.
3. Run from Android Studio.
4. Turn on WiFi on iPhone once the launch process has completed.

Comment: On Macbook M1 2020, when it stucked on launching, I closed my wifi and opened it. Then it let app to launch. Thanks for tip but I really wonder the exact problem.

Comment: I think in general XCode sometimes needs to do some cleanup, running from XCode without the WiFi workaround fixed the issue for me

Answer (score 1):

This is a workaround solution 
I was having this issue. I uninstalled the app from my device, opened the project in xcode, ran some build cleaning thing that appeared in the yellow triangle warning area, then built the app via xcode. Then uninstalled the app from device again. Then ran via android studio and it worked.

Comment: When this happens to me, just the step of applying the suggested changes in Xcode is enough to get it working again.

Answer (score 1):

Try executing the command: `killall -9 dart` and retry.

Comment: This one worked for me, I've been stuck on 'Flutter launching' message after trying to run in on physical Android device. After this command it installed it within a few seconds. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Basically, it is because of might some files
For me, this worked

Follows these steps: Go to Flutter > bin > cache
and delete the **Artifact** folder

Comment: Not recommended. Breaks pod install. Need to run precache for this to work again.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why, but the date and time in my test iPhone were changed to 1970. After changing it to the today, it was fixed.

Answer (score -1):

As in my case, I use one of following solutions to fix the issue:

#1. close WiFi on mac, then run from Android Studio; OR

#2. close WiFi on both mac and iphone, then run from Android Studio; OR

#3. enable hotspot on iphone and connect it from mac, then run from Android Studio;